# libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, centos7

I am trying to launch a script off of server I have which is running 64 bit CentOS 7, however whenever I launch the script I am getting this error in the server log.

```
Loaded log file: "server_log.txt".
SA-MP Dedicated Server

v0.3.7-R2, (C)2005-2015 SA-MP Team

[08:02:23]
[08:02:23] Server Plugins
[08:02:23] --------------
[08:02:23]  Loading plugin: crashdetect.so
[08:02:23]   CrashDetect v4.12 is OK.
[08:02:23]   Loaded.
[08:02:23]  Loading plugin: mysql.so
[08:02:23]   Failed (libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[08:02:23]  Loading plugin: streamer.so
[08:02:23]   Loaded.
[08:02:23]  Loading plugin: sscanf.so
[08:02:23]

[08:02:23]  ===============================

[08:02:23]       sscanf plugin loaded.    

[08:02:23]          Version:  2.8.1        

[08:02:23]    (c) 2012 Alex "Y_Less" Cole  

[08:02:23]  ===============================

[08:02:23]   Loaded.
[08:02:23]  Loading plugin: Whirlpool.so
[08:02:23]  
[08:02:23]  ==================
[08:02:23]  
[08:02:23]   Whirlpool loaded
[08:02:23]  
[08:02:23]  ==================
[08:02:23]  
[08:02:23]   Loaded.
[08:02:23]  Loading plugin: nativechecker.so
[08:02:23]   Loaded.
[08:02:23]  Loaded 5 plugins.

[08:02:23] I couldn't load any gamemode scripts. Please verify your server.cfg
[08:02:23] It needs a gamemode0 line at the very least.
```

As such the script is failing to launch. I believe the problem the line that reads libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. How do I fix this in terms of CentOS?

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly did you install MySQL?

Comment: Hey Michael, I followed this tutorial here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On CentOS 7, libmysqlclient.so.18 is in the package mariadb-libs so check if that package is installed and if not:

```
yum install mariadb-libs
```